# Shopify: Product grid - how overwrite a Product STOCK-OUT msg, with "Coming Soon" if it's in a ComingSoon collection

Tags: shopify, liquid

Our existing theme displays a 'Stock Out' banner over the product image if there is no stock.
We want to change this banner to "Coming Soon" if the Product is in a ComingSoon Collection.

The theme's 'product-grid-item.liquid   file contains:

```
  <a href="{{ product.url | within: current_collection }}" class="product-grid-item">
  <div class="product-grid-image">
  <div class="product-grid-image--centered">
    {% if sold_out %}
     <div class="badge badge--sold-out"><span class="badge-label">{{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}</span></div>
    {% endif %}
 ...
```

Which I changed to:

```
<!--  added ###For Test ###  -->
{% assign found_collection = false %}

{% for collection in product.collections %}
   {% if collection.handle contains 'Coming Soon' %}
      {% assign found_collection = true %}
      {% break %}
   {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
   {% if found_collection %}
      <div class="badge badge--sold-out"><span class="badge-label">Coming Soon</span></div> 
   {% else %}
      <div class="badge badge--sold-out"><span class="badge-label">{{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}</span></div>  <!-- this is the original line of code -->
  {% endif %}
<!-- end of added code -->
```

But is doesn't work, all 'no-stock' products display with the banner "Stock out"
Nb The actual Title of the ComingSoon collection is "Coming Soon ..."   - so the contains statement should work?

We could change the code to look for a Tag, but admin maintaining a tag would be more work.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is because `'Coming Soon'` is not the correct handle. A handle is part of your URL that can be found under Collection SEO inside the admin panel

e.g. store.myshopify.com/collections/my-collection -> my-collection is the handle

[image]

Comment: Doh!!  @TwistedOwl You are right.  It's 'coming-soon'.   Tks.